# preposition follow the word "interpreter"?

Tags: prepositions, vocabulary

Example Statement: 
He acted as interpreter between the Spanish locals and the tourists.

Should the preposition following "interpreter" be

"between" or "for" or something else? or should the entire sentence be reworded differently altogether?

Comment: yes this would be for non-professional casual interpretation

Comment: @HelloM It is also used when someone does it as an _unofficial part_ of their job, though. For example "The tour guide acted as interpreter when the party visited the local market."

Answer (score 0):

"For" is the preposition you're looking for. One can also translate as an action, in which case the word does not take a preposition. For example, consider these two sentences:

> She worked as a translator for the United Nations. She translated Korean into English.

In the first sentence, "translator" takes the preposition "for", but in the second sentence, "translated" takes an object ("Korean into English) but does not take a preposition.

Here are a couple ways to cast your example sentence:

> She worked as a Spanish translator for the tourists.
>
> She translated the local's Spanish into English for the tourists.